# Интеграция PL/SQL Developer с системой контроля версий. Как?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Добрый день! Для работы используем PL/SQL Developer. Хочется наладить взаимодействие с какой либо системой контроля версий. Может быть плагины какие то или еще что-то.
Кто сталкивался с подобными проблемами, как решали?
Поделитесь опытом или идеями.

Comment: На странице плагинов для `pl/sql developer` есть несколько для работы с системами контроля версий, такие как `Version Control Interface` и `TortoiseSVN-wrapper`. Но на сколько они хороши - я не знаю. http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldevplugins.html

Comment: lDrakonl, возможно, вы уже нашли решение и можете оставить свой ответ?

Comment: @4per ничего действительно удобного я так и не нашел. По этому пока ответа нет, после нового года буду снова искать)

Comment: А какие решения смотрели?

Comment: Указанные в первом комментарии

Answer (score 1):

Лучшим вариантом для реализации данной задачи, думаю, будет Subversion.

Во-первых, можно развернуть SVN-сервер на собственных ресурсах или же пользоваться облачным. Тут в зависимости от ваших требований и бюджета.

Во-вторых, имеются весьма достойные и многофункциональные клиенты – TortioseSVN и SmartSVN (pro). Я пользуюсь последним несколько лет и весьма доволен. TortoiseSVN бесплатный, за пользование SmartSVN придется заплатить. Если решитесь, посодействую в приобретении лицензий со скидкой.

> Дабы не нарушать правил сообщества, сразу оговорюсь, что не имею
>   никаких коммерческих отношений со SmartSVN и не получаю никаких выгод.
>   Просто это замечательное решение, которое, на мой взгляд стоит
>   популяризировать и которое уж точно отвечает на заданный вопрос.

Интеграция в IDE, по моему мнению, совершенно необязательна и не делает решение автоматически хорошим. TortoiseSVN интегрирован с проводником Windows, в то время как SmartSVN - кросс-платформенный и весьма удобен в отслеживать изменений "на лету" и логичных, понятных коммитов.

Comment: При таком подходе кажется Mercurial превосходит SVN. Интересует именно интеграция с PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: Interface Unknown, можете оставить хотя бы пару слов о том как именно происходят коммиты, проверка кода на компилируемость, как предохраняться от компиляции незакоммиченных модулей в базу?

Comment: @4per, OP не задавал вопросов о коммитах и предохранении (??) незакоммиченных модулей (???) в "базу". (Не базу, а репозиторий, кстати). И еще: я не знаю что такое "проверка кода на компилируемость". Видать, я безнадёжно отстал от жизни...

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown давайте продолжим обсуждении в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49642/chat-with-4per-and-interface-unknown)